# Finding ClearCase deliver target view using cleartool

Tags: view, clearcase, target, snapshot

I'm using ClearCase on Windows with snapshot views.

Is there a way to determine using cleartool which view will be used for deliver?

If there's a way that involves digging in the registry it's also ok.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can use any view on the destination stream you want in order to deliver.

Once the deliver is done, the view itself is not recorded.

During a deliver though, a `cleartool deliver -status` will tell you which view is currently used for said deliver.

Comment: @orgads CC picks the view you are mentioning during a [`cleartool deliver`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_deliver.htm) (the `-to` option mention the name of the destination view)

Comment: I mean the default one, without `-to`.

Comment: @orgads then I am not sure: I suspect it picks the first dynamic view you own on the parent stream (since by default, a deliver delivers to the immediate parent stream)